# Select a date larger than today using NotORM

Tags: php, pdo, notorm

I have a vey simple query (or so I thought) using NotORM:

```
$query = $db-> irregular
    ->select('id','name','starttime','endtime')
    ->where('customer_id',$_SESSION['user']['customer_id'])
    ->where("startdate > ? ", new NotORM_Literal("NOW()")) );
```

The "?" doesn't get replaced in the above instance. The query just reads

```
SELECT id, name, starttime, endtime FROM irregular WHERE (customer_id = '1') AND (startdate > ? )
```

How is this meant to work in NotORM?

Comment: `new NotORM_Literal("NOW()"))` produce result?

Comment: new NotORM_Literal is what I am using. The problem appears to be that NotORM is not swapping out the ? as it should.

Comment: It's probably working correctly. The `?` is a placeholder for the variable in prepared statements which will get sent to the server separately from the query.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. So if it's probably working correctly, then how do I actually get my desired end result? That is, how do I only select records for which start date is > now?

Comment: @Will I am unfamiliar with notorm, but try: `->where("startdate > NOW()");` and leave the second parameter out. Letting MySQL compute what `NOW` is is always the safest bet.

Comment: P.S. make sure you put an `@` before anyone's name or they won't get notified of your reply

Answer (score 3):

Assign the value of now() to a variable and use it in where clause

```
$now =new NotORM_Literal("NOW()");

$query = $db-> irregular()
->select('id','name','starttime','endtime')
->where('customer_id',$_SESSION['user']['customer_id'])
->where("startdate > $now")->fetch();
```

or

```
$query = $db-> irregular(array('customer_id'=>$_SESSION['user']['customer_id']))
->select('id','name','starttime','endtime')
->where("startdate > $now")->fetch();
```

Comment: $now =new NotORM_Literal("NOW()"); this will work. You can use a placeholder or the variable itself   ->where("startdate > $now")

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```js
        $jobs = $this->db->jobs->where(array("deleted" => 1,  "id" => $id))
        ->select('id', 'startDate')
        ->where('startDate < ?',$maxStartDate)
        ->where('startDate > ?',$minStartDate)
        ->order("id desc");
```